# Android: Getting a Twitter Lists/Statuses for a twitter client

Tags: java, android, twitter

I've been stuck on trying to inject a public twitter list from twitter using JSON.
I can get a search and a specific tweet from a user through a JSONObject.
If anyone has a code or could help me out, I'd really appreciate it!
Here is my search code. I know I need a new API source (which i have) but now 'm stuck.

```
public class ListviewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = getTweets("#Saints", 4);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewId);
        listView.setAdapter(new TweetItemAdapter(this, R.layout.listview, tweets));
    }

    public class TweetItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tweet> {

        private ArrayList<Tweet> tweets;

        public TweetItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Tweet> tweets) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, tweets);
            this.tweets = tweets;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi =
                        (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
            }

            Tweet tweet = tweets.get(position);
            if (tweet != null) {
                TextView username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.username);
                TextView message = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message);
                ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
                TextView created = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.created);

                if (username != null) {
                    username.setText(tweet.username);
                }

                if (message != null) {
                    message.setText(tweet.message);
                }

                if (image != null) {
                    image.setImageBitmap(getBitmap(tweet.image_url));
                }
                if (created != null) {
                    ListviewActivity la = new ListviewActivity();

                    created.setText(la.twitterHumanFriendlyDate(tweet.created));

                }
            }
            return v;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Tweet> getTweets(String searchTerm, int page) {
        String searchUrl =
                "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@"
                + searchTerm + "&rpp=100&page=" + page;

        ArrayList<Tweet> tweets =
                new ArrayList<Tweet>();

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler =
                new BasicResponseHandler();

        String responseBody = null;

        try {
            responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();


        try {
            StringReader myStringReader = new StringReader(responseBody);
            Object obj = parser.parse(myStringReader);
            jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.v("TEST", "Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        JSONArray arr = null;

        try {
            Object j = jsonObject.get("results");
            arr = (JSONArray) j;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.v("TEST", "Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        for (Object t : arr) {
            Tweet tweet = new Tweet(
                    ((JSONObject) t).get("from_user").toString(),
                    ((JSONObject) t).get("text").toString(),
                    ((JSONObject) t).get("profile_image_url").toString(),
                    ((JSONObject) t).get("created_at").toString());
            tweets.add(tweet);
        }

        return tweets;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(String bitmapUrl) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(bitmapUrl);
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static String twitterHumanFriendlyDate(String dateStr) {
        // parse Twitter date

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ", Locale.ENGLISH);
        dateFormat.toString();
        dateFormat.setLenient(true);
        Date created = null;
        try {

            created = (Date) dateFormat.parse(dateStr);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        // today

        Date today = new Date();
        System.out.println("<<<<<<" + today);
        // how much time since (ms)
        Long duration = today.getTime() - created.getTime();
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + duration + ">>>>>" + today.getTime() + ">>>>>" + created.getTime());
        int second = 1000;
        int minute = second * 60;
        int hour = minute * 60;
        int day = hour * 24;

        if (duration < second * 7) {

            System.out.println("right now");
            return "right now";
        }

        if (duration < minute) {
            int n = (int) Math.floor(duration / second);
            System.out.println("seconds ago");
            return n + " seconds ago";
        }

        if (duration < minute * 2) {
            System.out.println("about 1 minute ago");
            return "about 1 minute ago";
        }

        if (duration < hour) {
            int n = (int) Math.floor(duration / minute);
            System.out.println(" minutes ago");
            return n + " minutes ago";
        }

        if (duration < hour * 2) {
            System.out.println("about 1 hour ago");
            return "about 1 hour ago";
        }

        if (duration < day) {
            int n = (int) Math.floor(duration / hour);
            System.out.println(" hours ago");
            return n + " hours ago";
        }
        if (duration > day && duration < day * 2) {
            System.out.println(" yesterday");
            return "yesterday";
        }

        if (duration < day * 365) {
            int n = (int) Math.floor(duration / day);
            return n + " days ago";
        } else {
            System.out.println(" over a year ago");
            return "over a year ago";
        }
    }

    public class Tweet {

        public String username;
        public String message;
        public String image_url;
        public String created;

        public Tweet(String username, String message, String url, String created) {
            this.username = username;
            this.message = message;
            this.image_url = url;
            this.created = created;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't want to use any twitter clients like signpost or twitter4j ?,To post tweets you need to authenticate(like OAuth authentication)

Comment: Yeah, I would and working on it but looking for a good example.
But once I have it how do I get a list?